# Android Pop-up Tab Activity for the element of listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, android-tabactivity

I am developing one android application, having the listview activity. I displayed the activity. I want to place one pop-up tab activity having two tabs for the list view element. when the user clicks on the corresponding element, the pop-up tab should display and tab activity should be performed. Please help me with the corresponding sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "pop-up tab".   I'm not sure I'm clear as to what you want.  Maybe give an example or a screenshot.

Comment: pop-up tab means when we click on the list item of a list view, the tab activity should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i m getting right your question ,you want to open a TabActivity onItemClick ,which should look like a pop-up, I would like to suggest you to open a normal TabActivity when the user clicks on the corresponding element ..just put this in your manifest file :

```
<activity android:name=".YourTabActivityExample" ***android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog***">
```

**Theme.Dialog** will make it to look like a pop-up...